# Unable to Run .java file in Android Studio 4.0.1, Edit Configuration appears

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

While trying to Run the application, "Edit Configuration" appears and this below window opens:

[image]

How to proceed after this?

Pressing "Run" button does nothing.

Further on expanding the Templates drop-down, I am getting no-module in the Module box which is the only option available there.

[image]

Comment: u have any sdks installed?

Comment: @Sandrin Joy, Yes, I have SDK installed and able to run other programs successfully.

Comment: May be the api version of your sdk does not support the current app

Comment: @SandrinJoy, How to check this?

Comment: Ok , its not the api issue . Its because you don't have an activity to run (module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its because you haven't created the main activity / First activiy (module)**

**Also try refactoring your modules and package name**

*You will be promted to select an activity when starting a project, you might have missed it*

Comment: I have two activities in my project, and when I am trying to run the project, "Edit Configuration" appears as attached in the question. Further on expanding the Templates button, I am getting <no module> in the Module box. Thank you!

Comment: did you copied the activites from any other projects ? because in the manifest file , it might not have detected the file

Comment: no I am opening the whole project containing the activities. I have not copied the activities from other places.

Comment: try refactoring it

Comment: Thanks, Sandrin, I think there is some problem with SDK version and API level mismatch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221044/discussion-between-sandrin-joy-and-jackr).